# How to count zero values in a table in rows and write it to new field?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

This is a very simple task to do but I can't understand the right syntax.

I have a shapefile whose attributes are similar to the following:

```
FID Shape   FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 ...
0   Polygon 0      1      0
1   Polygon 3      0      7
2   Polygon 3      4      7
...
```

The number of **fields** and their **names** are always different.

I need to create a new field (let's name it NUM), and count the number of zeros in each row.

Example output:

```
FID Shape   FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 NUM
0   Polygon 0      1      0      2
1   Polygon 3      0      7      1
2   Polygon 3      4      7      0
```

I know how to create a new field, however I am not clear on the next steps.

---

**The working code:**

```
#path is path to shape file
def a(path):
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(path,"FID_*") #FID_* is wildcard to select a fields name 
  arcpy.AddField_management(path, "NUM", "SHORT") #create a field with name NUM
  cursor= arcpy.UpdateCursor(path) 
  for row in cursor:
    count=0
    for field in fields: 
      a= row.getValue(field.name) #take a value 
      if a==0: #if value=0 then value=value+1
        count+=1
    row.setValue("NUM", count)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
  del row 
  del cursor
```

Thanks [blah238](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/753/blah238), now I can eat pythons!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an outline of one way to do this. I'll leave the coding to you as an exercise.

1. Read the parameter(s) you need, such as the input `table`
2. Create a `fields` variable using [`ListFields()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001p000000), optionally passing in the expected `field_type`, e.g. *Long*
3. Add a new field, "`NUM`", to the `table` using [`AddField()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000)
4. Create a `cursor` variable using [`UpdateCursor()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000)
5. For each `row` in `cursor`:

   - Initalize a `count` variable
   - For each `field` in `fields`:

     - Get the `value` of `field` using [`row.getValue()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)
     - If `value` equals 0, increment `count` by 1
   - Set the value of the added field to `count` using [`row.setValue()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)
   - Call `cursor.updateRow()`, passing in the current `row`
6. Delete the `row` and `cursor` variables

Answer (score 3):

To do this you could open an UpdateCursor and run through each row using code (untested) like this.

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(path)   # path is your shapefile
for row in rows:
  count = 0
  if row.field1 == 0:
    count = count + 1
  if row.field2 == 0:
    count = count + 1
  if row.field3 == 0:
    count = count + 1
  row.num = count
```

If you have field1 to fieldN then you will need to also loop through the fields and use [**row.getValue()** and **row.setValue()**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000008r000000) to work with variable rather than hardwired field names.

**UPDATE**

Perhaps use my Answer as hints to complete @blah238's exercise :-)

Comment: I like the more "Pythonic" expression of: 
    count+=1 
instead of 
    count = count + 1
but that's just me.

Comment: blah238 is torturing me!!!

Comment: I aspire to be more "Pythonic" so will try to remember for next time - which is what I intended last time I saw that syntax - thanks!

Comment: @Vasiya sorry about that, but I'm sure you've heard the proverb "Give a man a fish and he eats for a day, teach a man to fish and he eats for a lifetime" :)

Comment: @blah238 The problem is that i am herbivore and don't eat pythons!!! =)